# The start date is not updated even though everything is automatic

Tags: ms-project

I prepared a work program in Ms Project. I manually wrote the beginning of the 7th column as 01.01.2023. I entered the duration of the job as 3 days and the completion date was automatically 03.01.2023. In column 8, I entered the start date of another job as "7FS+1" and it was 04.01.2023. I entered the work period 2 days and the end was 06.01.2023. Although everything has been formalized in the transactions, I am giving an example of the date 01.01.2023 in the 7th column. If it is changed to 03.01.2023, nothing changes even though the start of the work in the 8th column should be 06.01.2023. In other words, although the beginning of the 8th column was entered automatically, it behaves as if it was entered manually. How do I fix this problem

Comment: This part of the Stack Overflow forum is for questions/issues about programming, not for general project management questions. I suggest you re-post to the Project Management forum. For reference, Project specifying a column number in Project is meaningless, you need to identify the field (e.g. Start, Finish, etc.). Also, you should not manually enter any dates in Project. Project calculates dates based on the Project Start Date, task duration, and task dependencies. When you re-post, it would help to include a screen shot.